# Проверка на наличие в словаре нескольких элементов

Tags: python, словари, dict

У меня есть словарь `mydict`, и я хочу выполнять условие только, если в нём присутствуют сразу два элемента. Что-то типа такого не хочу:

```
if 'el1' in mydict:
  flag += 1
if 'el2' in mydict:
  flag += 1
if flag == 2:
   # My function
```

Но и вот это не работает:

```
if 'el1', 'el2' in mydict:
    #myfunction
```

Работает только:

```
if 'el1' in mydict and 'el2' in mydict:
    #my function
```

Существует ли более элегантное решение?

Comment: `all(k in mydict for k in ('el1', 'el2'))`

Comment: `len({'el1', 'el2'} & set(mydict)) == 2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант. Хотя выглядит тяжеловесно, но зато логично и понятно:

```
if all(map(mydict.__contains__, ('el1', 'el2')))):
```

Comment: Вариант @SergFSM хорош, но это решение мне нравится больше)

Answer (score 3):

Не знаю можно ли считать такое решение более элегантным, но, в принципе, можно проверить так:

```
mydict = {'el1':1, 'el2':2, 'el3':3}

print({'el3','el2'} <= mydict.keys())  # True (соответствующие ключи есть в словаре)
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю в общую копилку ещё такой вариант:

```py
mydict = {'el1':1, 'el2':2, 'el3':3}

print(not None in (mydict.get(i, None) for i in ['el1', 'el2']))
# Вывод: True
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]